# C# - Saving Console Game Values

Tags: c#, variables, save

I'm making a Console Application which is a text-based game, and I need to save values such as HP and Money and be able to retrieve them later.

I've tried using Settings, but the problem is that they rely on file name and file path, which means that if one of them changes, the whole save will not be loaded (and it's a problem because most players will change the file name).

So I want to be able to save all values of variables to a text file and to retrieve them later.

Is that possible to make such thing efficiently?

Thanks if someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the simple classes for file operations provided by the IO namespace.
Here you could find numerous examples

[Common I/O Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But to summarize, I suggest follow this pseudocode

- Find the folder where you want to store your data
- Create a file in this folder
- Prepare a buffer with your variable to write to
- Close the file

So let's start with the first task

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
string folder = Path.Combine(folder, "myappNameDataFolder");
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
string dataFile = Path.Combine(folder, "myappNameDataFile");
```

Here we try to build a folder inside the special folder reserved by windows to the application data common to all user of this computer. See the enum [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is the best place to store your values because you have all the right permissions to read/write files there.

Now you are ready to create a file in that folder using the common StreamWriter class

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dataFile, true))
{
   ....
```

In the above statement, the StreamWriter is created inside a using block to ensure its closing and destroying at the end of the enclosing block.

Now you could build the buffer to store your variables. Here I show just one variable and I suppose that these variables are available in this point of the code

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("HP=" + valueForHPToSave.ToString();
   .... other variables follow this line
```

Write the buffer to the stream and close and dispose the stream

```
    sw.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

The inverse operation (read back the values when your app starts) is just a matter to use a StreamReader, ReadAllLines and split every line at the equals sign to recover the original values

Another approach is to use the built-in [serialization mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/ms233843%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by the framework.
In this scenario you build a class named `AppState` and you mark it with the `Serializable` attribute

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

[Serializable()]
public class AppState
{
     public int HPValue {get; set;}
     .... other variables to store/read from the serialization stream
}
```

The intent is to have an instance of this class written and loaded from disk where you store all the variables needed to restore the state of your application.

Now you could declare in your main class a global instance of the `AppState` class and you start to store the values during the execution of your app.

```
public class Program
{
     public static AppState stateVariables = new AppState();

     public static void Main()
     {
          // read back the values of stateVariables here... (see later)
          ...
          stateVariables.HPValue = 100;
          ...
     }
}
```

When the application closes you write the instance of your class using code like this

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
string folder = Path.Combine(folder, "myappNameDataFolder");
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
string dataFile = Path.Combine(folder, "myappNameDataFile");
using(Stream stateStream = File.Create(dataFile))
{
    BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    serializer.Serialize(stateStream, stateVariables);
}
```

When the application starts you read the values back using a similar approach

```
public class Program
{
     public static AppState stateVariables = new AppState();

     public static void Main()
     {
          string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
          string folder = Path.Combine(folder, "myappNameDataFolder");
          Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
          string dataFile = Path.Combine(folder, "myappNameDataFile");
          if (File.Exists(dataFile))
          {
              using(Stream stateStream = File.OpenRead(dataFile))
              {
                  BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
                  stateVariables = (AppState)deserializer.Deserialize(stateStream);
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Please, take note that I haven't tested this code, and to fully understand, read more about [Serialization on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/ms233843%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much, but isn't there a simpler way? For example, I've seen someone using <string> data and things like this to write values faster into the text file.

Comment: +1. for sample of constructing save location. I'd avoid inventing custom text format instead of using standard JSON/XML... Also based on comments some custom binary serialization may be needed to achieve some (undefined) performance goals.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov probably you are right. Too many details are missing and this is just a starting point for the OP

Comment: Not clear what do you mean with <string> however there are many ways to write data on disk and many formats (XML, JSON, binary). This example is just to show the basics to write text data and it is not the fastest way to go, but nevertheless, it is simple and, unless you have thousand of megabytes to store, is not a performance game changer in better or worse.

Comment: So what is the shortest way to write all variables to a text file and to retrieve them later? I know you already showed me but there probably is a slightly shorter way.

Comment: There is no point in 'write all variables' to a text file. You should define first what variables are required by your application to restore its previous state, then you could group these variables in a global class called AppState and then SERIALIZE/DESERIALIZE this instance on disk. See my edit about Serialization

Answer (score 0):

One option is to save into a file (or file in sub-folder) inside My Documents.

To get path - [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [MyDocuments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 var root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
 var fileName = Path.Combine(root, "MyGame.sav");
```

Than read/write your settings any way you like.

You can also consider other folders like `LocalApplicationData`...

Comment: Reading/writing is the major problem for me... Is there a highly efficient, yet not too complex, way to do that for all of the variables?

Comment: @BlueRay010... Storing JSON or using XmlSerialization is super easy, but not "highly efficient" from most points of view (except correctness, readability of data, and ease of writing code). You need to provide way more information to get good answer for "highly efficient" portion of your question.

Comment: OK, what I meant is saving ALL variables to a .txt file, and later retrieve them from the text file. I want to do this as short as possible. How can I do it?