# trying to use serializing to save and load variables from console app (c#) ( answered)

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, console-application

it was Answered by a comment from Chris.

i had to also do `equipedShield = stateVariables.equipedShield; equipedWeapon = stateVariables.equipedWeapon; healthPotionCount = stateVariables.healthPotionCount; playerExpEarned = stateVariables.playerExpEarned;`
to make it load,  thank you chris.

**my question is can i use variable names to store values? or do they have to be actual numbers?**

i found a post here [C# - Saving Console Game Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010737/c-sharp-saving-console-game-values)
i choose to do the serializing but instead save on mydocuments so i could actually find the txt file ( and i did)
to load in main:

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        folder = Path.Combine(folder, "RNGgameSaveFiles");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        string dataFile = Path.Combine(folder, "RNGgameSaveFileV1");
        if (File.Exists(dataFile))
        {
            using (Stream stateStream = File.OpenRead(dataFile))
            {
                BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
                stateVariables = (AppState)deserializer.Deserialize(stateStream);
            }
        }
```

it seems to save it just fine, but when loading everything is empty.

like :

```
static int roundsPlayed;
    static decimal money = 0;
    static decimal totalMoneyEarned;        
    static double totalScore;        
    static int totalKills;
    static int totalLosses;
```

saved as:

```
stateVariables.totalLosses = totalLosses;
        stateVariables.totalKills = totalKills;
        stateVariables.totalScore = totalScore;
        stateVariables.totalMoneyEarned = totalMoneyEarned;
        stateVariables.money = money;
        stateVariables.roundsPlayed = roundsPlayed;
```

or is that what is messing it up for me?

i made that class called appstate:

```
    namespace rngGame
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class AppState
    {
        public int roundsPlayed { get; set; }
        public decimal money { get; set; }
        public decimal totalMoneyEarned { get; set; }
        public double totalScore { get; set; }
        public int totalKills { get; set; }
        public int totalLosses { get; set; }
        public bool owned01 { get; set; }
        public bool owned02 { get; set; }
        public bool owned03 { get; set; }
        public bool owneds01 { get; set; }
        public bool owneds02 { get; set; }
        public bool owneds03 { get; set; }
        public double healthPotionCount { get; set; }
        public int equipedWeapon { get; set; }
        public int equipedShield { get; set; }
        public int playerLevel { get; set; }
        public int playerExpEarned { get; set; }
```

to save and exit
( this part does work, it does create the file):

```
static void closeAndSave()
    {
        string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        folder = Path.Combine(folder, "RNGgameSaveFiles");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        string dataFile = Path.Combine(folder, "RNGgameSaveFileV1");
        using (Stream stateStream = File.Create(dataFile))
        {
            BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            serializer.Serialize(stateStream, stateVariables);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: At a minimum, [Serializeable()] should be [Serializeable]

Comment: thank you i changed that, still don't work though. ( nothing changed same file is being written)

Comment: And when you say "loading everything is empty", you mean your stateVariables members are all null/0/unpopulated? I see you've got some code that puts values into stateVariables and serializes it, but you have to do the opposite as well - ie, read the values from it and set your static members to those values.

Comment: lol, i feel silly now i figured that it would put them back in order automatically, thank you, i did the reverse and now it works. edit, how do i set your comment as answer?

Comment: Moved the answer to an answer so you can close. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some code that puts values into stateVariables and serializes it, but you have to do the opposite as well - ie, read the values from it and set your static members to those values.